# Wordpress Gravity Forms Dynamic passing of id of form

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I can hardcode the shortcode for Id in template but I read that this is not a good practice, my question is how to dinamicly pass Id of form so that one day when user needs a new form he can change it without calling a developer(me)?

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>                 


   <?php echo do_shortcode("[gravityform id='1' title='true' description='true']"); ?>

<?php endwhile; else : ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put it in an (advanced) custom field, or simply in the content.

Answer (score 0):

Use Advanced Custom Fields and create an Options page where the shortcode can be edited, examples are available here:

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/options-page/

Then in your theme you put something like `the_field('contact_form, 'option');` instead of the `echo do_shortcode(...);` part you have now. Afterwards the user can edit the field and insert a new form.

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using ACF or are open to using it, you might consider this plugin which will allow the user to select from a list of Gravity Forms:

https://github.com/stormuk/Gravity-Forms-ACF-Field